# How to trigger a function on Enter key

Tags: javascript, search, enter

I would like to add code that allows me to use the enter key in addition to a cursor click to initialize a google map at the location that is submitted via a text box. I have the click part down, the enter key, not so much :(

```html
    <input id="address" type="text">
    <input id="search" type="button" value="search" onClick="search_func()">

    <script>
      function search_func() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        initialize();
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code? You didn't give very much. Also, make sure to properly format your code blocks by putting four spaces before each line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>WisdmLabs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

</head>

<body>

<input id="address" type="text" onkeypress="handle(event)" placeholder="Type something here">
<input id="search" type="button" value="search" onClick="search_func()">

<script>

function search_func(){
 address=document.getElementById("address").value;
 //write your specific code from here 
 alert("You are searching: " + address);
}

function handle(e){
 address=document.getElementById("address").value;
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
  //write your specific code from here
     alert("You are searching: " + address);
    }
 return false;
}

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Feel free to ask any doubts or suggestions.

Comment: Formatting? Explanation? Why are you including jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
function search_func(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('search').click();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add a listener to your text box that fires `search_func` on keydown, when the key pressed is enter (13 is the `keyCode` for <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```html
<input id="address" type="text" onkeydown="key_down()">
<input id="search" type="button" value="search" onClick="search_func()">

<script>
  function key_down(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
      search_func();
    }
  }

  function search_func() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    initialize();
  }
</script>
```